# Replace params data from name to id before save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to replace item name to item id before save in database.

**This is my controller code**

```
def create
    @supplier = Supplier.new(supplier_params)
      if @supplier.save
        item_code = params[:supplier_item][:item_ids]
        item_id  = Item.where(:item_code => item_code).pluck(:id)
        item_params = params.require(:supplier_item).permit(item_ids: [], location_ids:[], supplier_prices: [])
        items = item_params[:item_ids].zip(*item_params.values_at(:location_ids, :supplier_prices))
        items.map do |item_id, location_id, supplier_price|
          supplier_item = SupplierItem.new({
            item_id: item_id,
            location_id: location_id,
            supplier_price: supplier_price,
            supplier_id: @supplier.id
          })
          supplier_item.save
        end
        flash[:success] = "New supplier created"
        redirect_to supplier_path(@supplier)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end
```

So this code now save item_ids["Apple", "Banana"]. But I want to save this in id form which is like this item_ids["1", "3"]

**This is my view code**

```
<%= f.label :item, class: 'required'%>
<% items = Item.where(company_id: current_user.company.id)%>
<%= text_field_tag "[supplier_item][item_ids][]", nil, {list: 'browser-item'} %>
      
        <% items.each do |item| %>
             <option data-value = <%= item.id %>  value = <%= "#{item.item_code} - #{item.name}" %>></option>
         <% end %>
```

So I try this to get item id of the item name

`Item.where(:item_code => item_name).pluck(:id)`

This one give me all the item id I were selected. So how should I replace this id into the params

Comment: HI Abdullah, you need to pass ids in the params instead of string values

Comment: Hi @Vishal. but I just want to show the name in the option tag. I don't want to show the id. What I trying to do is I want to take the item code value and find the item id by using item code and replace in the parameter.

Comment: You do realize that option tags have a value attribute and an inner text? So you can have `<option value="1">Whatever text you want</option>` and get both a user friendly label and values that are usable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: In general this code is crazy overcomplicated and its hard to tell what the original problem that its trying to solve is. If you want any help that will actually untangle this mess you need to explain the problem and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: I'm guess what you actually need is just something like `form.collection_select(:item_ids, @items, :id, :name, multiple: true)` and to actually set up proper assocations between and remove the database queries from the from the view.